# Nifi w/ Docker on Gitpod : No UI Access

Tags: docker, networking, apache-nifi, gitpod

I'm running a basic docker compose for nifi 
(spinning on a Gitpod workspace)
And I cant seem to be able to acces the NiFi UI

```
version: '3'
services:
  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi:latest
    container_name: nifi
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      # HTTP
      - 8080:8080/tcp
      # HTTPS
      - 8443:8443/tcp

    environment:
      NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST: '0.0.0.0'
      NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT: 8080
```

Same with :

```
docker run --name nifi -p 8080:8080 -e NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST=0.0.0.0 -d apache/nifi:latest
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

What am I missing ?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST` environment variable to `127.0.0.1` or the host IP?

Comment: I just noticed that your _"Same with :"_ example is missing ` -e NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=8080` which is not the same as port mapping.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try using port forwarding:

- https://www.gitpod.io/docs/configure/workspaces/ports#port-forwarding
- An easy way is to just open your Gitpod workspace in local VSCode, as outlined in the above link.